# Is linear regression equivalent to the support vector regression with a linear kernel?

Tags: regression, svm

I notice the objective function of the linear regression and the support vector regression (SVR) with a linear kernel could be the same, except for the SVR has two error constraints for each data instance if both methods choose the same error functions (e.g. L2 error with $\epsilon=0$).

I wonder whether this means that they always get the same optimal solution for $w$ and $b$, and they are equivalent in this case, even if they use different optimisation methods to learn the optimal solution?